# Type emitted value based on Input's value

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building a select component which should emit a string if only one item can be selected and an array of strings when the `@Input() multiple` is true.

```
type SelectValue = Project['id'] | Project['id'][];

Component({
  selector: 'app-project-select',
  ...
})
export class ProjectSelectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() readonly valueChange = new EventEmitter<SelectValue>();

  @Input() readonly value: SelectValue;
  @Input() readonly multiple: boolean = false;
  ...
}
```

How can I properly type this? The goal is to use the component like this:

```
<app-project-select
    (valueChange)="changeProject($event)"
    [multiple]="false"
/>
```

Here I'd like to have the information that `$event` will be a `Project['id']`/`string` and not an array. Doing this in React would be easy with unions but I can't wrap my head around it with Angular.